# TensorFlow session run graph defined outside under tf.Graph()

Tags: python, session, tensorflow

When initializing `tf.Session()`, we can pass in a graph like `tf.Session(graph=my_graph)`, for example:

```
import tensorflow as tf

# define graph
my_graph = tf.Graph()
with my_graph.as_default():
    a = tf.constant(100., tf.float32, name='a')

# run graph
with tf.Session(graph=my_graph) as sess:
    a = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('a')
    print(sess.run(a))  # prints None
```

In the example above, it prints `None`. How can we execute an operation defined inside `my_graph`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the intended behavior, but I can see why it would be surprising! The following line returns a `tf.Operation` object:

```
a = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('a')
```

...and when you pass a `tf.Operation` object to `Session.run()`, TensorFlow will execute the operation, but it will discard its outputs and return `None`.

The following program probably has the behavior you're expecting, by explicitly specifying the 0th output of that operation and retrieving a `tf.Tensor` object:

```
with tf.Session(graph=my_graph) as sess:
    a = sess.graph.get_operation_by_name('a').outputs[0]
    # Or you could do:
    # a = sess.graph.get_tensor_by_name('a:0')
    print(sess.run(a))  # prints '100.'
```